# adding text to an xls file with bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, excel, bash, shell

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to write to an xls file with a bash script. Situation is outlined below.

I have a cronjob that runs every monday and generates an xls and emails to my client. This xls is filled with data from a MySQL DB. when the report is empty and the client attempts to open it, it shows as corrupt. Originally I addressed this issue by excluding empty files from the email with an if statement. However, the constraint is that all 4 reports much reach the client - empty or not.

So my question is, can I simply add a row of text at the top with a bash script so the file never "empty"? I'm not an expert in bash scripting by any means, so feedback here would be great. thanks!

Tony

Comment: How exactly is the report generated? Can you add a "dummy" record on to each source query such that there are never zero "results"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any pure bash implementation for writing XLS files.  There are solutions in other languages such as Perl, Python, or PHP.  If you think outside the box there is another option available to you.  You mentioned that you currently use an `if` statement to not attach empty files.  Create a blank spreadsheet in a program like MS Excel, optionally enter some text in A1 like "No records", save it, and transfer that to a known location on the server that runs the cronjob.  Rather that skipping the attachment, whenever you detect an empty file in your `if` statement just attach the blank "No records" template XLS file.  You may need to copy the template to a temporary location before attaching if you need to rename the file.